# React Formik Load data from api

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new in React ,I checked this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-master-details-crud-example?file=users%2FAddEdit.jsx

but if I use 'useEffect' inside the Formik I am getting error message but its working in live example

**Error Message**
*React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function*

```
return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => {
        const [user, setUser] = useState({});
        useEffect(() => {
          if (!isAddMode) {
            // get user and set form fields
            userService.getById(id).then(user => {
              const fields = ["title","firstName","lastName","email","role"];
              fields.forEach(field => setFieldValue(field, user[field], false));
              setUser(user);
            });
          }
        }, []);
        return (
          <Form>
            <h1>{isAddMode ? "Add User" : "Edit User"}</h1>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-group col-5">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <Field name="firstName" type="text" className={ "form-control" + (errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? " is-invalid" : "")                 }
                />
                <ErrorMessage name="firstName" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
              </div>
            </div>
         <Form>
        )
        }}
    </Formik>
  );
```

thanks for the solutions

Comment: can you replicate you code in codesandbox?

Comment: I have updated the code in codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-demo-zfxsz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use hooks you must have to use functional components I think your main component is class component that's why it is giving error

Comment: I am new in react, can you guide where I creating mistake -https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-demo?file=users%2FAddEdit.jsx.  this code is working in stackblitz. But if i run in local machine its throwing error message

Comment: I have checked you codesandbox link can you give me the name of the component in which you are facing issue?

Comment: AddEdit.jsx (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-demo-zfxsz?file=/src/users/AddEdit.jsx)

Comment: Yes its working in live ( codesandbox  and stackblitz) but if i run the same code in local machine then i am getting  Error - >"React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function " (this was my main question )

Comment: Yes,  I have export the codesandbox  code and checked , its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218507/discussion-between-dishant-desai-and-anish-manchappillil).